# How to add links to telegram/website/X to new fungible Solana token?

Tags: metadata, solanaspl-token

I've seen some tutorials how to update/create metadata for new token to be displayed properly in solanascan and phantom wallet
metadata.json fields that work normally with metabos updated uri
are name, symbol, description, image

But how to add Telegram/X/Website links?